# Ways of organizing a lot of cards

Tags: cards, organization

For an intranet application we've developed a way for users to create dashboards.

Each dashboard is named and then displayed as a card. In the beginning this was very easy to work with. Now we have users with over 30 dashboards and they're struggling to find the one they're looking for.

These are the options we've discovered ourselves:

- Allow users to create folders in which they organize everything themselves
- Add a filter at the top which allows users to filter by dashboard content
- Add a "favourites" mechanism where users can tag certain dashboards as their favourite and display them in a reserved 'favourite' section
- Tagging dashboards

Do you happen to know other resources I can review that discuss additional options? Do you know of any other?

[Update]
A little more context and a picture;
A dashboard in our system is basically a canvas where users can add charting widgets focused on visualizing date. They can name these dashboards and also share them between other users for collaboration. The system itself can be compared to an IOT asset management solution. So it's not uncommon to have several dashboards for a single asset while maintaining multiple assets. A dashboard can be about multiple assets as well.

[image: A small number of dashboards]

Comment: It will probably depend a lot on the use case of the dashboards, for example, if these dashboards are for ad campaigns you could sort by most recent, that way older non-running campaigns are at the bottom and new running campaigns are right up front.

Comment: Just use an "old fashioned" multi-column list (like the "Details" view of Windows explorer)? It may not be as trendy, but if I had 30+ things to manage I'd much rather them in such a list.

Answer (score 1):

Can we see an image of what it looks like?

As always prototype and test.

> Allow users to create folders in which they organize everything themselves

This sounds like a step in the right direction. However, limit the amount of folders, else you could find yourself in the same position.

> Add a filter at the top which allows users to filter by dashboard content

Unless you have data the proves that users know what they are looking for based on what they've made, then this could work. Else my assumption is that they won't always know what they are looking for—especially if they've created a lot.

> Add a "favourites" mechanism where users can tag certain dashboards as their favourite and display them in a reserved 'favourite' section

You'll run into the same issue that you're in now, unless you limit the number of favorites and the users know how many they can favorite

> Tagging dashboards

Again, limit the amount that you can tag.

Out of all the solutions I'd be curious to test the creating folders and favorites. Creating folders is going to add more work for the user, but will give the user freedom. favorites is the easiest, but less freedom compared the the creating of folders.

**EDIT:**
I've seen the photo and still stick to what I've said. In the end it comes down to testing. I can give you my opinion on what I'd like, but I'm not your user. If you can't test, then I'd probably go with allowing users to create collections(folders), but instead of just having the user create all of them add some pre-made folders. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Oddboll. At the moment we can't test due to the limited amount of resources and funding forced onto us. But your answer is helpful :-)

Answer (score -1):

USE CASE: The user needs to be able to find one dashboard out of many.

There's more than one way of accomplishing this - and they can be combined.

The simple way would be to list the dashboards and have the user sort them by name, date (and hopefully data groups).

The "data groups" could also allow filtering.

```
NAME                   DATE CREATED      DATA GROUPS
Employee Attendance    11/4/2017         Employees, Hours Worked, xxx, yyy
Sales Report (Expos)   12/1/2017         Sales Report, aaa, bbb
Sales Report (blah)    12/12/2017        ccc, ddd, eee
...
```

You can also use a carousel view and allow the user to thumb through his dashboards.

[image]